# How long before steak is at room temperature?

Tags: beef, refrigerator, timing

I've got a piece (of about **300 grams**) dry-aged rib-eye in the fridge, at around **6 degrees Celsius**. I want to let it "get to room temperature" (which technically is about **21 degrees Celsius** for me) before I cook it up to about 55 degrees Celsius core temperature.

Is there any good rule of thumb to determine how much time I should minimally / optimally let it sit outside the fridge before slapping it into the pan?

Comment: My new rule of thumb is : don't do it.  You get a better medium-rare if the meat's cold so not as much of the outside over cooks.

Comment: On a side note, since asking this question I've been pre-heating steaks in the oven with a meat thermometer to a little above room temp just before searing on high heat (I might get a sous-vide setup later on to get more control).

Answer (score 3):

According to [Serious Eats](http://www.seriouseats.com/2013/06/the-food-lab-7-old-wives-tales-about-cooking-steak.html), a **210 gram steak** in sitting in a **21° C room** managed to go from **3° C** to **10° C**... in **2 hours**. For a larger steak going up all the way to 21 degrees, it would take longer. The take-away from that article is that it's not worth it and does not affect the resulting steak.

Comment: The mass of the steak is much less meaningful than the size/geometry. A flank steak and a filet, for example, will have totally different heat transfer properties. So a "larger steak" does not necessarily take longer to warm up... but a *thicker* steak of the same size, or even smaller, could.

Answer (score 2):

I usually let a steak sit out for 45 minutes to an hour before cooking it. But the real answer is to get a meat thermometer, preferably an instant-read digital one, and use that to not only tell you when your steak is at room temp, but also to tell you when it's done cooking.

Comment: I've got a meat thermometer, but not one that *predicts when* it'll reach a certain temp ;-). A thermometer only tells me *if* it's at the right temp, not *when it shall be* at the right temp.

Comment: @Jeroen Draw a graph and extrapolate

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe remembering (thanks to Newton) that the graph is exponential rather than linear :)